# Migrate ASP.NET application to cloud - maintain anonymous access but limit to client users

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cloud, hosting, anonymous

I am sure this must have come up for people before. We sell an ASP.Net application that can be used by anonymous users and we have system administration areas secured with forms authentication. The software is installed on-premise at each client site and made accessible on their intranets.

We are looking at providing a hosted solution in the future. My question is how I can restrict access to the application to only users from a particular client but still provide anonymous access? Regular Joes on the internet should not be able to access it.

I was thinking LDAP may play a part and I could compare the Active Directory domain of the client perhaps but I don't have much experience in this area.

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you mean "only users from a particular client", you mean they should use a program that you made, and not be able to use their own browser? Sounds like that's a case for certificates.

Comment: I think the intent is to allow users associated with an entity with a subscription to use the application without requiring log in credentials, while blocking people who aren't associated with an entity that has a subscription?

Comment: @rogerdeuce has it right. We will have multiple instances of this web application on our servers but we only want our clients to be able to access their own instance without logging in.